# Heroku node server deployment not responding to client

Tags: node.js, heroku, websocket

I am trying to deploy a very simple node server to heroku that looks like this:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });
console.log("Server started")

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    console.log('Client connected');
     setInterval(() => {
        wss.clients.forEach((client) => {
            if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                var testObject = {
                    message: new Date().toTimeString()
                }
                client.send(JSON.stringify(testObject));
            }
        });
    }, 5000);
    ws.on('close', () => console.log('Client disconnected'));
});
```

Package.json

```
"engines": {
    "node": "12.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "server": "node server.js"
  },
```

If I start it locally, my clients prints out the timestamps.
I now deploy it to heroku. The log shows:

> 2020-05-07T09:30:30.429508+00:00 app[web.1]: > websocket-node@1.0.0
>   start /app 2020-05-07T09:30:30.429509+00:00 app[web.1]: > node
>   server.js 2020-05-07T09:30:30.512985+00:00 app[web.1]: Server started

I then change my clients configuration

```
// const subject = webSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
const subject = webSocket('ws://whateverwhatever.herokuapp.com:8080');
```

But I receive no answer from the server. What am I missing?

Comment: instead of `8080` you need to bind to `process.env.PORT`. Heroku provides you a random port which you need to bind to. Second the ws URL does not contain a port number at the end. It is automatically translated by the DNS into a ip address + port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Tin Nguyen changed threeline - took 30sec.

Client code:

```
const subject = webSocket('ws://fierce-dawn-73363.herokuapp.com');
```

Server code:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: PORT });
```